# UWP - Change App Icon dynamically

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, icons

I recently received a real headache problem for UWP apps. 
Basically I would like to change the main Icon of my app depending on an action. 
Let's say I would like to change the App Icon if a certain user logs into my app so that he does not see default App Icon after closing the app.

I found different links which refer to work on tiles, which works perfectly fine. But I did not come up with a solution to change the App's Icon.

Is there a way like in iOS to use `AlternateIcons` or in Android to just call an `Alias`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tiles are technically the icons in the UWP world. You can update the live tiles as you desire with notifications and they can provide richer visual surface than classic icons.

For the `App List` and `Taskbar` icons however, those are just static and you cannot change them at runtime. They come from the `Package.appxmanifest` *Visual Assets* section, so you have to define them ahead of time.

You however use [Badge notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/badges) to display simple info next to the app icon in the Task bar as well as on the main app tile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
So basically there is no way of changing the icon in the App List and Taskbar at runtime right?
But is there a way to let's say create an overlay for them at runtime? 

The idea come from android where I use an alias activity to change my app's icon. 

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Yes, there is no way to change the icon itself. But you can add the badge overlay badge as a "notification" above the icon.

Comment: Great I will give it a try :) 
Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding :-)